# How to get youtube playlist texted details with python

Tags: python, youtube-api, playlist

I read YouTube Data API (v3) and try youtube.playlistItems.list at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list

but no respond

Is there a way without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list

find respond in history and set perpage to 50 get all the content